# React JS google map not refreshing upon selecting a new location from search

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have recently added a search bar to my React Google Maps application, but upon selecting a value from the search bar, the map is not re-rendering. I have attempted to set a key on the Google Map component, but it is not working. Below is the code for my application:

```js
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import usePlacesAutocomplete, { getGeocode, getLatLng } from 'use-places-autocomplete';

const MapContainer = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const [selectedPlace, setSelectedPlace] = useState(null);
  const [mapKey, setMapKey] = useState(new Date().getTime()); // Add mapKey state
  
  const containerStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '400px',
  };

  const center = {
    lat: 37.7749,
    lng: -122.4194,
  };

  const onLoad = (map) => {
    setMap(map);
  };

  const handleSelect = async (address) => {
    try {
      const results = await getGeocode({ address });
      const { lat, lng } = await getLatLng(results[0]);
      setSelectedPlace({ address, lat, lng });
      setMapKey(new Date().getTime()); // Update mapKey state
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleLoadScriptError = (error) => {
    console.error('Load Error:', error);
  };

  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="YOUR_API_KEY" libraries={['places']} onError={handleLoadScriptError}>
      <div style={containerStyle}>
        <GoogleMap key={mapKey} mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} center={center} zoom={10} onLoad={onLoad}>
          {selectedPlace && <Marker position={{ lat: selectedPlace.lat, lng: selectedPlace.lng }} />}
        </GoogleMap>
        <PlacesSearchBox onSelect={handleSelect} />
      </div>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};

const PlacesSearchBox = ({ onSelect }) => {
  const { ready, value, suggestions: { status, data }, setValue, clearSuggestions } = usePlacesAutocomplete();

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = (address) => {
    setValue(address, false);
    clearSuggestions();
    onSelect(address);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder="Search..." />
      {status === 'OK' && (
        <ul>
          {data.map((suggestion, index) => (
            <li key={index} onClick={() => handleSelect(suggestion.description)}>
              {suggestion.description}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not updating center position. After setting the selected values of lat/lng, its started to work.

```
 const center = {
    lat: 37.7749,
    lng: -122.4194,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all key is not necessary and it is not going to work either because the component doesn't seem to receive that prop.

https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/develop/packages/react-google-maps-api/src/GoogleMap.tsx

But it seems to be that  receives an `option` prop that could be useful and there is a hook inside of that component that reacts to that prop triggering an useEffect and probably start to re-render the map (see the file above).